# How to get registry host, port from registryId in AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

How to get registry host, port from registryId in AWS ECR. The following call provides very less information about the AWS ECR registry and doesn't provide the registry host or port information

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-registry.html

Comment: What do you mean by container port and actually container at all? ECR is for storing images, but not containers

Comment: I didn't mean the container, but the registry host and port something like 113394024569.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com which contains all the repositories

Comment: looks like you looking for [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-repositories.html) command

Comment: If you asking about common part (registry URL) of repositories, it will be `{{AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}}.dkr.ecr.{{REGION_NAME}}.amazonaws.com`. So you can understand the URL without retrieving it by command

Comment: Can't an AWS account have more than one private registry, if so how will the url naming convention work

Comment: `describe-registry` command returning only one `registryId` at output JSON (it is string but not list with single string included), so not sure if registries may be multiple.